# How do I write a Hibernate Criteria to match case-insensitively and trim whitespace?

Tags: hibernate, trim, case-insensitive, removing-whitespace

I currently have a restriction on a criteria of `MyClass` to match values of `MyClass.propertyName`:

```
Restrictions.ilike("propertyName", matchString)
```

Is it possible for this to match values of `MyClass.propertyName` with leading or trailing whitespace?

---

Here is the regex equivalent of what I am trying to match:

```
\s*foo(\s*|\s+.*)
```

Answer (score 1):

If `matchString` is `"%foo%"`, and the propertyName value is `"   foo   "`, then the restriction will accept this property. That's the whole point of using the like operator.

Comment: "fook", "bafoon" and "kungfoo" should not match.  Is this still valid?

Comment: No, it's not. You'll probably have to use regexes, but this will certainly force you to improve the Hibernate Dialect or to use specific criteria restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 way to do it:

1. Make `matchString` like: `"%foo%"`
2. Use Restriction specific: 
     `Restrictions.ilike("propertyName", matchString, MatchMode.ANYWHERE)`

Comment: "fook", "bafoon" and "kungfoo" should not match. Is this still valid?